# Issue with Game Display and Controls

Tags: 11.10, games

I bought a game off of the Humble Indie Bundle 4 a few months ago called "And Yet It Moves". It worked fine for ages, but then I stopped playing it.

Yesterday, I decided I wanted to play it a bit more, the game looked like it was going to start fine, the logos of the games producers faded in and out, the music started, but then I realized that the pause menu wasn't showing up, and that the in-game cursor wasn't moving at all. Outside of the game, the cursor was moving fine and everything was working, just this game. I'd rather not have to re-install it since I'm quite a bit of the way through, and I've searched the net but can't find anything.

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 on HPnc6400 laptop with Intel Integrated Graphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was to do with my internet connection. My Wireless was up but internet was down, causing the internet to appear to be working very slowly, but not actually working at all. Meaning that And Yet It Moves would get stuck connecting, not realising there was no internet connection causing a black screen with no explanation. Either having a working internet connection or disconnecting the wireless on the computer itself solved the problem. The answer by Broken Rules is also right if you have an older version of the game.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like an older bug we've already fixed.

Let's hope this is the same one. All it takes to get rid of the black screen bug is to update to the latest version.

Since you've bought the game via HIB4 all you need is use the download link you've received after the purchase to download the latest version (v. 1.2.2.).

You can also drop a message on our [forums](http://brokenrul.es/forum/) or contact us from our [site](http://www.brokenrul.es/) in case the latest update did not work out to be the solution.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Thank you for the answer on this, lets hope that the user's issue is solved with your advice. I took the liberty to edit your answer to remove the email address and include links to your web page and forums. I hope that was not a step too far. Regards

Comment: Turns out it was to do with my internet connection. My Wireless was up but internet was down. Meaning that And Yet It Moves would get stuck connecting, not realising there was no internet connection causing a black screen with no explanation. Either having a working internet connection or disconnecting the wireless on the computer itself solved the problem. Thanks anyway though, I'll upvote.